# I want to run an Android fragment over the cordova Activity to incorporate the YouTube Android Player API within my hybrid app

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, android-youtube-api

I am wondering if there is a way to incorporate YouTube Android Player API within the ionic/cordova hybrid application using the custom Cordova plugin(specifically for Android). the youtube video needs to play as part of the cordova activity in form of fragment with control over the positioning of fragment in the hmtl/js code.  Is there any way I can achieve this? Please help :)